# Array lists to print customer objects

Tags: java, arraylist

How would I use an array list of type Customer(Which has 2 child classes, nonmember and member) to print out all customer objects using a comparison? in other words, I want to check the array list at a certain index and check if it is a Non-member or member object and print output accordingly. here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();

for(int i = 0; i < customerList.size(); i++)
{
    if(customerList.get(i) == // nonmember)                     
    {
        // want to use toString in NonMemberCustomer class
    }
    else // member
    {       
        // use toString in MemberCustomer class to print output.
    }
}
```

```
public String toString()    
{
    return "\nMember Customer:" + super.toString() +
           "Collected Points:\t" + pointsCollected + "\n\n";
}
```

```
public String toString()
{
    return "NonMember Customer:" + super.toString() +
           "Visit Fee:\t\t" + visitFee + "\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your arraylist using `Customer` as the parametric type:

```
// So that the polymorphism would work
List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Second, you don't need an `if/else` statement to print the respective `toString`()s of your objects; just **override** the `toString()` method in each of your classes & [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) shall take it from there.

```
for(int i =0; i < customerList.size();i++) {
    // Implicit call to the toString() method
    System.out.println(customerList.get(i)); 
}
```

The classes: (e.g)

```
class Customer {
    // properties & methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("The customer's toString !");
    }
}

class Member extends Customer {
    // properties & methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("The member's toString !");
    }
}

class NonMember extends Customer {
    // properties & methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("The nonmember's toString !");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the insight. I will try this out.